# SQL Server 2017: 'VERIFY_CLONEDB' is not a recognized option

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to clone a database on SQL Server 2017 so I'm following the command from [D. Creating a clone of a database that is verified for production use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-clonedatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-creating-a-clone-of-a-database-that-is-verified-for-production-use):

```
DBCC CLONEDATABASE (AdventureWorks, AdventureWorks_Clone) WITH VERIFY_CLONEDB;    
GO
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 4, Line 7
> 'VERIFY_CLONEDB' is not a recognized option.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is returned if you query `SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'AdventureWorks';`

Comment: @DaleK `compatibility_level: 110`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running in compatibility mode 110 which is SQL Server 2012. However `VERIFY_CLONEDB` was only introduced in SQL Server 2014: From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-clonedatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> This option is available starting with SQL Server 2014 (12.x) SP3, SQL Server 2016 (13.x) SP2, and SQL Server 2017 (14.x) CU8.

If you are happy to change the compatibility mode you can do so with the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140; -- 2017
```

And ensure that you have CU8 installed.

Comment: sorry I was too soon to celebrate... All databases are showing 140 now, but I'm still receiving the same error. I've tried restarting the MSSQLSERVER service and restarting the SSMS, but no luck.

Comment: And just to double check, what happens if you run `select @@version`?

Comment: `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: )`

Comment: It says the feature is available in SQL Server 2017 CU8. According to Microsoft, CU8 is `v14.0.3029.16`, so I need to install CU8. Will try that and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: After I installed the upgrade, the issue was resolved.